# How to set log level in QAF / Qmetry framework?

Tags: qaf

I would like to reduce the log level displayed in the console during my automation run in QAF / QMetry framework. When I tried playing around in log4j.properties, it is not showing any difference in the console logging. Tried following in log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.com.qmetry.qaf=ERROR
log4j.rootCategory=off

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Follow=false
```

**Note: Not seeing any ws.log file created as mentioned in the below property**

```
log4j.logger.com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ws=DEBUG, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.file=${outputDir}/ws.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1GB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Log4j is set in the Maven config: (I have also tried putting the log4j config in the src folder).

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${testSuiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <reportsDirectory>${test.results.dir}/${run.time}</reportsDirectory>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <org.uncommons.reportng.xml-dialect>testng</org.uncommons.reportng.xml-dialect>
                        <org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output>false</org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output>
                        <log4j.configuration>file:///${resource.dir}/log4j.properties</log4j.configuration>
                        <outputDir>${output.dir}</outputDir>
                        <test.results.dir>${output.dir}/html</test.results.dir>
                        <json.report.root.dir>${test.results.dir}</json.report.root.dir>
                        <json.report.dir>${output.dir}/json</json.report.dir>
                        <selenium.screenshots.dir>${output.dir}/img</selenium.screenshots.dir>
                        <selenium.screenshots.relative.path>../img</selenium.screenshots.relative.path>
</systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It is set in maven: I have updated the info in top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set log4j properties file location. Refer sample ant or maven project. If you are not familiar, easiest way is to move `log4j.properties` file under src directory.

Comment: I have added additional info to the post. Log4j properties are set in Maven and I have also tried to drop Log4J.properties in the src folder, but it is not picking up the settings.

Comment: In this case when running using maven it should take effect. If not it may have conflict with other dependencies or path is wrong. You may see some information in console on execution start.

Comment: Log4j property issue has been rectified after upgrading the QAF version to 3.0.0. Now the property configs are taken.